MLIR: error: custom op 'tosa.int_div' is unknown
I got a problem when try mlir-opt tool with tosa dialect
Is that's because I'm uisng the old-version mlir (LLVM 18.1.8), Does it will fixed after I update mlir library to newest?
(tf) ➜  cases git:(master) ✗ /home/cds/workspace/MLIR-Tutorials/build/cds-opt --CdsDemoPass /home/cds/workspace/MLIR-Tutorials/cases/tosa/ops.mlir
running my mlir pass cds-demo
/home/cds/workspace/MLIR-Tutorials/cases/tosa/ops.mlir:262:8: error: custom op 'tosa.int_div' is unknown
  %0 = tosa.int_div %arg0, %arg1 : (tensor<13x21x1xi32>, tensor<13x21x3xi32>) -> tensor<13x21x3xi32>

The version clang I'm using, The mlir library based on this.
(tf) ➜  cases git:(master) ✗ clang --version 
clang version 18.1.8
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /home/cds/app/clang+llvm-18.1.8-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-18.04/bin

Or maybe because enable the tosa diealect not in right way.
I init it by
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  DialectRegistry registry;
  mlir::registerAllDialects(registry);
//   mlir::registerAllExtensions(registry);
  mlir::registerAllPasses();

  llvm::outs() << "running my mlir pass cds-demo\n";

  mlir::cdsdemo::registerPasses();
  return asMainReturnCode(MlirOptMain(argc, argv, "toy-opt-cds", registry));
}

I want to know why tosa int_div is not recognized by mlir, it's an internal dialect.

The problem was resolved after I updated mlir to the latest with tag llvmorg-19.1.4.
